# Using bootstrap multiple autocomplete tags

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, autocomplete, tags

I have a table `news` with `id`, `title`, `body` and another table `tags` with `id`, `name`. These two tables are related by a pivot table `news_table` with `news_id`, `tag_id`. Relations are created on modals and foreign key constraints are set on the pivot table. I have a controller `manageData` containing a function `insertNews` and a form in a view where i get the data entered.

What i want to do is have a field in my form like a text input field which will act like a dropdown where i can add multiple words as tags which will be taken from the tags table and shown to me as suggestions. if the word doesn't exist in my tags table i want it to be added there

I have tried some methods but with no success

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the many JS scripts with suggestion feature to allow users to choose or add tags, like [this one](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-tagsinput/).

When a form is submitted, just iterate over the tags, submitted by a user and build an array of IDs of the existing tags and an array with new tag names. Then use `sync()` method to sync existing tags and `attach()` method to add new tags.

Or just `sync()` method with one array which will have both IDs and tag names.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships